# Docker react image doesn't hot reload

Tags: reactjs, docker

Red all the posts around. Tried with lower `"react-scripts"` (mine is 5.0.1), used `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'`, basically everything on the first two pages on google.
Hot reloading still doesn't work. My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  database:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toma123
      MYSQL_DATABASE: api
      MYSQL_USER: toma
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: toma123
    ports:
      - '4306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    volumes:
      - ./../api:/var/www/api
    depends_on:
      - database

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./../api:/var/www/api
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - database

  react:
    container_name: react
    build:
      context: ./../frontend
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/home/app/node_modules

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  node_modules:
    driver: local
```

And my react `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if a lot of your application is in Docker it doesn't mean you need to exclusively use Docker.  Since one of Docker's primary goals is to prevent containers from accessing host files, it can be tricky to convince it to emulate a normal host live-development environment.

[Install Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on your host.  It's likely you have this anyways, or you can trivially `apt-get install` or `brew install` it.

Start everything *except* the front-end application you're developing using Docker; then start your application, on the host, in the normal way.

```bash
docker-compose up -d nginx
npm run dev
```

You may need to make a couple of configuration changes for this to work.  For example, in this development environment, the database address will be `localhost:4306`, but when deployed it will be `database:3306`, and you'll need to do things like configure Webpack to proxy backend requests to `http://localhost:8080`.  You might set environment variables in your `docker-compose.yml` for this, and in your code have them default to the things they are in the non-Docker development environment.

```js
const dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost';
const dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT || 4306;
```

In your Compose setup, do not mount `volumes:` over your application code or libraries.  Once you get up to the point of doing final integration testing on this code, build and run the actual image you're going to deploy.  So that section of the Dockerfile might look like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  react:
    build: ../frontend
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    # no volumes:
    # container_name: is also unnecessary
```